# Browser-sync + Gulp - Reloading fails if no server is running

Tags: javascript, gulp, reload, browser-sync

I'm building my gulpfile and faced a problem with browser-sync. I'm trying to reload my browser in html task after `gulp.dest()` but it keeps failing. Here's the part of the gulpfile which fails.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    server      = require('browser-sync'),
    $           = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task( 'html', function () {
    return gulp.src( 'path/to/html/*.html' )
        .pipe( $.fileInclude() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'path/to/dest/' ) )
        .pipe( server.reload() );
});

gulp.task( 'serve', ['html'], function () {
    server({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'path/to/directory/'
        }
    });

    gulp.watch( 'path/to/html/*.html', ['html'] );
});
```

I'm sure that the problem is the reloading part, since when I comment it out everything works like they should. I'd appreciate any help with this since I've been stuck with this for a quite a long time now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `server` initialized?

Comment: What do you mean by initializing? I've required everything at the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks for adding the `require` calls, that's exactly what wasn't clear to me. Can the problem arise from the fact that you `reload()` server before starting it in `serve`?

Comment: Yeah no problem! I should've done that before. Yes it's probably why it happens but it's kind of tricky because I need to call `html` task without server running. One solution would be to create two different tasks but I wouldn't like to go that route. It's weird enough that when using `server.stream()` this problem doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task( 'build-html', function () {
  return gulp.src( 'path/to/html/*.html' )
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe( $.fileInclude() )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( 'path/to/dest/' ) );
});

gulp.task('serve', ['build-html'], function(done) {
  browserSync({
    open: false,
    port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: ['.']
    }
  }, done);
});

function reportChange(event){
  console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
}

gulp.task('watch', ['serve'], function() {
  gulp.watch('path/to/html/*.html', ['build-html', browserSync.reload]).on('change', reportChange);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is old style but, this is how you should initialize.

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload = browserSync.reload;
```

And call it like

```
.pipe(reload())
```